# Дублирование рабочего стола из консоли proxmox на все мониторы windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, proxmox

Доброго времени суток.

Что имеем:
Proxmox 7.1-8. На нем крутится виртуалка WIndows 10. В виртуальную машину проброшено 3 видеокарты. На каждой видеокарте висит несколько мониторов.

Проблема:
Необходимо чтобы рабочий стол из консоли proxmox дублировался на все остальные физические мониторы.
Использование win+p (режим "Повторяющийся") не решает проблему когда мониторов больше 2х.

Понимаю, могут возникнуть вопросы в целесообразности такого использования видеоадаптеров, и не меньше вопросов связанных с выбором win-10 в качестве основной системы, но это зависит не от меня. Я работаю на уже предоставленном оборудовании и не могу ничего менять.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Библиотека: [pymultimonitor](https://pypi.org/project/pymultimonitor/).

Например:

```
from pymultimonitor.core.DisplayTopology import DisplayTopology
from pymultimonitor.cinterface.constants import DisplayConfigTopology

DisplayTopology().set_topology_clone()
```

Comment: Спасибо, это сработало. Важное замечание - при изменении числа мониторов необходимо вновь выполнить скрипт, в остальном все работает отлично даже после перезагрузки.